# OpenGL save screenshot in Android NDK

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, android-ndk, screenshot

I'm using OpenGL with Android NDK to overlay some information on the image taken from the camera. I now need to save a screenshot of the app every time new information is displayed.

I found a couple of examples of how you would do it in C++ normally (without Android), however most solutions seem to use various libraries - most of which seem unavailable or unreliable on Android. I am trying to save the image as PNG, however saving as a bitmap would be fine for now.

Comment: Do you use SurfaceTexture for camera preview? Otherwise, you have the big task to grab separately the preview frame.

Comment: @AlexCohn I'm really new to this so I'm not completely sure if I have a good understanding of the code yet. By my understanding, what I do have is a framebuffer containing a texture that is sent to a GLSurfaceRenderer in java.

Comment: Oh, I read your question again - this image from camera is static, not a live preview. That definitely makes your life a huge bit easier.

Comment: @AlexCohn I solved it by just writing the raw data to a file and then converting the file into what I need. Not the nicest thing to do, but since my user won't need the file really quickly, I can just have another thread in java reading the raw file and converting it.

Comment: @AlexCohn oh btw it is a live preview of the camera, it's just that I can afford a low enough framerate that you could consider it static for now